# Unity: How to handle GetButton situation with the New Input System?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

In the old system we could:

```
Update{
   if(GetButton("xxx"){
   // Do something until its released...
   }
}
```

How do I recreate this in a new system?

Comment: Did you read the quick start guide on https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html ?

Comment: In particular read [Migrating from the old input system -> `UnityEngine.Input.GetButton`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.1/manual/Migration.html#unityengineinputgetbuttonhttpsdocsunity3dcomscriptreferenceinputgetbuttonhtml)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```cs
Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("xxx")) { 
        .....
    }
}
```